# laravel middleware almost always redirects

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Can you guys please, help me. My project running on Laravel 5.3 locally everything works fine, I uploaded my project on server, it also works as it should. Then I uploaded my project on another server - and it almost always redirects to login page. Here's logic - if user is not authenticated, it redirects to login page. If user is  authenticated, user will get access to content. On my 'another' server - when I go to main page it gives

```
page isn’t working
redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

So it's not Laravel's error. When I go to login page, it loads, but when I log in, it redirects to main page with that `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. and it always works in this way.

routes

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

login controller

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}


/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 */

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $user = $this->findOrCreateUser($request);

    if($user)
    {
        Auth::login($user);

        $user->incrementVisists();

        if($user->count_visits > 3)
        {
            return redirect('/campaigns');
        }else{
            return redirect('/');
        }

    }else{

        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request))
        {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);

    }

}

/**
 * Validate the user login request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required',
        $this->password() => 'required'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}

/**
 * Get the login password to be used by the controller.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function password()
{
    return 'password';
}

/**
 *  find or create user
 */
public function findOrCreateUser(Request $request)
{
    $auth = $this->getUserDataFromRemote($request->username, $request->password);

    if($auth == "OK")
    {
        if(User::where('name', $request->username)->count() < 1)
        {
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request->username,
                'email' => '',
                'role' => 1,
                'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            ]);
        }else{
            $user = User::where('name', $request->username)->first();
        }

        return $user;
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

I found out that it happens cause `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        //return redirect('/home');
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

But don't know how should I fix it. Even if problem is in this middleware, why it works locally and on my first server?

main route

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomesController@index')->name('mainPage');
```

index method in WelcomesController

```
public function index()
{
    if(\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->count_visits > 3)
    {
        return redirect()->action('CampaignsController@index');
    }

    $welcome = Welcome::first();;

    //activate the first menu item
    Menu::get('mainMenu')->find('chooseAWebsite')->active();
    foreach(Menu::get('mainMenu')->find('chooseAWebsite')->children() as $item){
        $item->isActive=false;
    }


    return view('welcome.index', compact('welcome'));
}
```

campaignsController

```
 public function __construct() {
   $this->middleware('auth');
   $this->middleware('menu');
}

public function index() {

    $campaigns = Campaign::where('user_id',Auth::id())
        ->paginate(25);

    $layouts = \App\Layout::pluck('url', 'id');

    return view('campaigns.index', compact('campaigns', 'layouts'));
}
```

Comment: It seems something is redirecting you back to /login while you are logged in. Can your share your '/' route controller please?

Comment: thanks for reply. I added it

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any redirects in your CampaignsController?

Comment: there are redirects only in `update`, `store` and `destroy` methods. in `CampaignsController@index` it only retrieve data from database and return view. i added code to question

Comment: So if the code is identical on all servers have you done the obvious checks of clearing the view/application cache check composer is using the same lock file as the other servers etc?

Comment: @Leo thanks for reply) can you please, tell in more details? you mean `php artisan cache\view:clear` ?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS in you dashboard view? if so, is your server running nginx? because sometimes this redirect loop is from a misconfiguration of nginx with https protocol